# Where to configure the AutomaticRetryAttribute filter in Hangfire?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

We are using Hangfire, failing jobs should be retried. We use the following approach to specify the number of retry attempts:

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 3 });
```

Our question is: where do we have to configure this filter? At the program which puts the items into the queue or at the processing service which processes the queue items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure the filter at the processing service, it is the same as the per method attribute as stated in the docs

Comment: I can't find that in the docs. Can you point me to the correct page? I only found http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html and couldn't find the information there.

Comment: The global filter works the same as the Attribute, is there in the link that you posted

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core 7.0

```
 // Add Hangfire services.
    builder.Services.AddHangfire(x=> x
            ..........................................
            ..........................................
            ..........................................
            ..........................................

            ).UseFilter(new AutomaticRetryAttribute 
            { 
                Attempts = 5, 
                LogEvents = true, 
                OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Fail, 
                DelaysInSeconds = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3}
            })
```

Comment: Does not work, there is no UseFilter after AddHangFire

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution may help to those guys, who are still looking for the solution on Hangfire Retries flow.
If you are using .Net6 then in the Program.cs
OR
If you are using .NetCore5 or older version then in the Startup.cs
In "configure the HTTP request pipeline section"

app.UseHangfireDashboard();//below to the this line add below global filter
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 3, DelaysInSeconds = new int[] { 1200 } });
Where Attempts = 3 re-tries thrice on failure and DelaysInSeconds is the duration gap to retry after 20 mins = 60*20 = 1200 seconds.